# What does this mean when justifying static classes?

Tags: c#

1) Static class members can be used to separate data and behavior that is independent of any object identity: the data and functions do not change regardless of what happens to the object. Static classes can be used when there is no data or behavior in the class that depends on object identity.

What does it mean by functions do not change regardless of what happens to the object? How can a function change? Static variables, yes, but functions?

What does "object identity" mean? Would that be for example, a specific house in a house object? (So we deal with a specifically chosen house). So a static class would not work on any house objects?

2) If I don't work with instance state, should I always use static classes? What's the difference between a static and instance class working with instance state? All I can think of is the static class will only be of 1 instance and thus 1 instance means many calls will be queued if the class worked with instance state (if there is thread synchronisation)? Obviously, static state should only need a static class.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to question 1)**

Imagine that you have a Car object with a field called speed. If you create a new car object and then set the speed property by using this function

```
public void SetSpeed(int value)
{
   this.speed = value
}
```

the function SetSpeed would depend on the car object being initialized so it could access the speed property. Hence, without an initialized car SetSpeed would not be invokable. Had the function, however, been static, then it would not have access to any specific initialized car object, only other static defined objects.

**Answer to question 2)**
A static function does not have access to any instance declared functions or variables, so having a static function work with instance state items does not make sense.

Comment: To help me a long, got any more examples of when to use 1)? So a static class/method might be to change something not related to a car instance - such as?

Point 2), fair enough.

Comment: A static method doesn't belong to any instantiated object, so it doesn't change anything but the parameters of which is was passed when invoked. You could have a static method on a class that would instantiate a new object of the specific type. You see this kind of behaviour on the HttpWebRequest object that you cannot instantiate on your own, instead you have to use the HttpWebRequest.Create/CreateDefault method to create instances of that class.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to treat static methods as a way of creating helper functions which to relate to the specific class so I can use them globally without having to instantiate any objects. A very simple example would be:

```
public class Person
{
    private string name;
    private DateTime dob;

    public Person(string name, DateTime dob)
    {
         this.name = name;
         this.dob = dob;
    }

    public int Age { get { return CalculateAge(this.dob); } }
    public string Name { get { return this.name; } }

    public static int CalculateAge(DateTime dob)
    {
          // use dob to work out age.
    }

}
```

So in the above scenario you can see if I create a person object, I can encapsulate the calculation of the age using a readonly property. However, if I needed to work out the age of someone based on a date, outwith the specific person object, I can use the static method i.e.

```
// object usage
var p = new Person("Joe Bloggs", DateTime.Parse("10/11/1981"));
Console.WriteLine(p.Age);

// static usage
Console.WriteLine(Person.CalculateAge(DateTime.Parse("10/11/1981"));
```

Comment: Because CalculateAge only acts on DateTime data, I'd prefer to make it a non-static 'Age' property of Person (which can act on the `dob` instance data), or a *private* static method of Person (to help implement the Age property), or a public method of the DateTime class.

Comment: @Chris, as stated above this is just a very simple example. It is just to demontrate how you use a static method and why.

Comment: I tend to use static methods to operate on static data, or, to operate on parameters whose type is of that same class, for example "static bool AreFriends(Person lhs, Person rhs)" is a static method of Person which takes two Person instances as its parameters (and whose implementation can access private members of each passed-in Person instance).

Comment: Which is fine, bottom line is, static methods can be used for whatever you want them to do as long as they don't rely on the instance of the object.

Comment: This is a very helpful example. It's been said they don't rely on an instance of an object and I was going to request an example. This solves that.

Comment: Hope it helped you understand what exactly a static method is and when to use it :)

Answer (score 2):

Static methods are little more than global functions tagged to a specific class.  They're used primarily as a workaround in languages without multiple inheritance.

If you have a function that calculates circumference from radius and this function is needed  all over in your project, you can make a class as such:

```
public static class geometry_facilities
{
  public static Double circumference (Double radius)
  {
    return radius * 2 * Math.PI
  }
}
```

and you can access this function anywhere with:

```
geometry_facilities.circumference (6.730);
```

The Object oriented way to do this would be to *not* use static anything and instead multiply inherit from geometry_facilities to pull in the functionality.  Static methods are primarily used in OO languages with only single inheritance to facilitate code reuse.

Comment: C# can inherit multiple interfaces.  Can this be used as a workaround?

Comment: Interfaces cannot contain any actual code, only function definitions - so no.

Answer (score 1):

Static classes do not have an instance.  When your assembly is loaded, all static methods in all static classes become available to the application immediately.  Another way of saying this is, you don't have to create an instance of a static class, using the new operator, in order to use the methods in that class.

What this means in practical terms is that you won't handle state in a static class, which essentially makes the methods immutable, and therefore thread-safe.  No thread queuing takes place on a static method; all calls are executed immediately.  There is no object identity because, as you correctly pointed out, there are not multiple instances of the class available.

Extension methods and utility methods are typical examples of  static methods in static classes.  They generally accept an object, operate on it, and return a new or modified object of the same or a different type.  No state is kept between calls because, as one poster pointed out, since there is no class instance, there is no place to keep class variables.  Any variables that are defined in the method for processing purposes go out of scope (are lost) when the method returns.

Answer (score 1):

> What does it mean by functions do not change regardless of what happens to the object?  How can a function change? Static variables, yes, but functions?

I think it's badly worded: that instead of "static data and functions do not change regardless of what happens to the object", it would be better to say, "static data and functions do not affect, and are unaffected by, changes to specific instances of the object."

For example, given a class like ...

```
public class Car
{
  int m_speed;
  public int Speed { set { m_speed = value; } }
}
```

... some static data and a static method might be like this ...

```
public class Car
{
  int m_speed;
  public int Speed { set { m_speed = Math.Max(value, s_maxSpeed; } }
  //static data and static method
  static int s_maxSpeed;
  public static void SetMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed) { s_maxSpeed = maxSpeed; }
}
```

... in this example, the static `s_maxSpeed` value exists, and the static `SetMaxSpeed` method can be called, regardless of whether any `Car` instance even exists.

> What does "object identity" mean? Would that be for example, a specific house in a house object? (So we deal with a specifically chosen house). So a static class would not work on any house objects?

I believe that "object identity" and "object instance" mean the same thing: they are synonyms. The `object.ReferenceEquals` method lets you test an object's identity, i.e. see whether two object references are pointing to the same ('identical') instance/identity.

> If I don't work with instance state, should I always use static classes?

'Yes' (to a certain extent) because everything (even non-instance state) has to be within some kind of (e.g., static) class.

> What's the difference between a static and instance class working with instance state? All I can think of is the static class will only be of 1 instance and thus 1 instance means many calls will be queued if the class worked with instance state (if there is thread synchronisation)?

One difference is that static data always exists, whereas instance data doesn't exist before/until the instance is created. You're right that a static class is similar to a singleton object.

However, even if thread synchronization is needed, the "synchronization" doesn't happen automatically (no matter whether it's static or a singleton), and instead in either case it must be implemented explicitly (e.g. by using the `lock` keyword etc. etc.).